# nodeJS + codeigniter not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, codeigniter, socket.io

Im trying to make real time update table on my codeigniter project. So I choosed to use node.js and socket.io for it. I have installed node, express, socket, mysql and other necsassary plugins bet it seems that I'm missing for something. This my `assets/js/node_app.js` code:

```
    var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = socket.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log("New client !");

    client.on('test', function(data){
        console.log('Data received: ' + data.test);
    });
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log("Listening on 8080");
});
```

and this is what I have included in my view:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var socket = io.connect('https://www.domain.com:8080');
        socket.emit('test', {test: 'working'});
    });
```

and what I'm expecting to see is the output in the console: (i can see it)

> Listening on 8080

and when I'm open the page console should be appended (can't see this)

> Data received: working

but nothing happens and I have no clue why. When I open firebug I see

```
GET https://www.domain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1446497073274-0
```

in red so its failed with response "null"

also I'm using socket.io.js code from here https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js

Comment: Have you tried with the official version of socket.io ??

Comment: What do you mean official version? I'm using the script provided by socket.io creators.